# Is "for all who" grammatical?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, determiners

The context is:

> The blog for all who want to learn German.

I feel like this is not correct, but the only alternative I can think of is:

> The blog for all those who want to learn German.

While just being one word longer this feel boring and stiff to me. Is the original sentence perhaps grammatically correct, after all?

Comment: The original line is fine (though it's not a sentence).

Comment: @JLG - And should probably be "The blog for all who want German to learn" ;-)

Comment: @mgb: Or rather 'The blog for all who German to learn want.'

Comment: @BarrieEngland - "Only a German is so discourteous to his verbs"?

Comment: @mgb: In fact, German verbs come second in a main clause. It's only in subordinate clauses that they go to the end.

Comment: @BarrieEngland - so `want` comes second and the spare verbs go at the end don't they?

Comment: So in German a relative clause with "who" would be subordinate and thus "want" goes to the end... the very end... and it would be:

The blog for all who German to learn want.

As for the discourtesy... the verbs like to hang out at the end. So as soon as they don't have to do main clause chores they will go to the terrace. For us Germans this adds an element of suspense, fulfillment and "un-interuptability-ness" to the language that English will never know ;)... kidding... I love both languages for their special traits

Comment: @mgb: In a main clause, the finite verb is the second element in a sentence and any non-finite verbs occur last. (Subject to any correction by Emanuel.)

Comment: I'm rather shocked that nobody on here got the Sherlock Holmes reference. kids today on programming.so not getting hitch-Hikers Guide ones is bad enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insofar as "one" is commonly accepted to mean a single specific person, "all" is  reasonably considered a well-understood demonstrative pronoun meaning a group of individuals.  "All those", thus, becomes a redundant pair of pronouns ("those" also being a well understood demonstrative pronoun meaning a group of individuals)` and "the people' being, effectively, an appositive of "all".

So, "all who want to learn German" seems as acceptable to me as "all those who want to learn German", but "all wanting to learn German" would be equally, if not a bit more, acceptable, though, I might choose "wishing" over "wanting".

Answer (score 1):

Building on what @Carlo_R. and @JLG have said, it would seem to me that if you can replace *all* with *people* (or *all people*) and still have your tagline be grammatical, then *all* is fine on its own.

Comment: I'd just quibble that it's not necessarily "all people". I could say, "There are many books on my shelves. All were purchased from Amazon." Meaning "all the books" of course.

Comment: @Jay, agreed. The extra clarity was merely to illustrate.